# .net interfaces with generic methods, errors in implementation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, generics, interface

Bear in mind, this code works in C#, but not in VC++.net (infuriating).  I'm wondering where my mistake is on here.

Given the code:

```
public interface class iTest
{
   public:
   generic <typename T>
   virtual void AddCriteriaList(List<T> ^CriterionList);
};

generic <typename Q>
public ref class IUseInterface : iTest
{
   public:
   generic <typename T>
   virtual void AddCriteriaList(List<T> ^CriterionList)
   {

   }
};
```

I get the error error C3766: 'IUseInterface' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'void iTest::AddCriteriaList(System::Collections::Generic::List ^)'

The strange thing, is if I remove the generic constraint (Q) on IUseInterface, the error goes away.  I don't understand how making my class generic would have ANYTHING to do with a generic on a specific function.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Totally different languages ...

Comment: They're extremely similar, and should follow the same compilation rules in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to compile just fine if you don't use a List parameter, and just use a T parameter. Just use add them all in a loop or something, its a few lines of extra code, but will compile for you.

Comment: Why thank you.  That is a very astute statement.  You sir, are the astutest of all of us.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the answer for that, but this works, if it's good enough for you:

```
generic <typename T>
public interface class iTest
{
   public:
   virtual void AddCriteriaList(List<T> ^CriterionList);
};

generic <typename Q, typename T>
public ref class IUseInterface : iTest<T>
{
public:
   virtual void AddCriteriaList(List<T> ^CriterionList)
   {
   }
};
```

Comment: I'm trying very hard to have any solution not have iTest itself be generic.  I have a collection of iTests, and if I type them, they'd have to all have the same constraint, for instance, Dictionary<long, iTest<SomeTime^>^>, won't work out.  Thanks though